# How to create a query and add columns to select sequentially?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I need to construct a query where the selected columns in the result are changing. How can I add columns to the result progressively similar to `.filter`:

`query = session.query(User).filter(name == 'Hansen').filter(country == 'Spain')`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sqlalchemy [Query](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#the-query-object) class has an [add_columns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.add_column) method that can be used for this.

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

q = session.query()
for c in cols:
    q = q.add_columns(getattr(MyTable, c)) 

res = q.all()
```

As the name suggests, the method will accept more than one column expression.

```
q.add_columns(*list_of_columns)
```

Query.add_entity would be used to add an orm entity, such as a model class, to the query.

```
q = session.query()
q = q.add_entity(MyTable)
# Fetch objects, not just columns
list_of_objs = q.all()
```

Comment: Is it the same with `.add_entity`? Because `.query` takes entities according to the documentation, but when I write something like `.add_entity(MyTable.col)` I get an error I haven't understood yet.